# CSS: how to apply properties to ::first-line in <p> and then other properties to the rest of text?

Tags: html, css

I have a block of text that the structure repeats a lot. 
Instead of having to write `<br>` all the time for the line change, I wanted to set that in the `<p>` style. The problem is i have already used a styling for the first line, and then when i try to define the line break for the rest of the text, it deformats the first line.
How can i solve this?

Here is my HTML and CSS

```css
p#texto_anuncio::first-line {
  color: #800000;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  white-space: pre-line;
}
p#texto_anuncio {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

```html
<p id="texto_anuncio">
  Vente d'un appartement entièrement rénové au coeur de xxxx situé Rua xxxxx.
  <b>Appartement de charme très lumineux, 4ème étage, sans ascenseur, 130 m2, 2 balcons, 1 grand balcon fermé.</b>
  - 6 pièces, dont 3 aveugles. - Cuisine - électroménagers intégrés. - 2 salles de bains modernes. - Finition design avec respect des matériaux anciens. - Parquet ancien bois massif rénové . - Climatisation. Envoi de photos sur demande.

</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it is deformats the `::first-line` is because you have to put the text inside your paragraph right next to tag, with no whitespace:

```css
p#texto_anuncio::first-line {
  color: #800000;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  white-space: pre-line;
}
p#texto_anuncio {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

```html
<p id="texto_anuncio">Vente d'un appartement entièrement rénové au coeur de xxxx situé Rua xxxxx.
  <b>Appartement de charme très lumineux, 4ème étage, sans ascenseur, 130 m2, 2 balcons, 1 grand balcon fermé.</b>
  - 6 pièces, dont 3 aveugles. - Cuisine - électroménagers intégrés. - 2 salles de bains modernes. - Finition design avec respect des matériaux anciens. - Parquet ancien bois massif rénové . - Climatisation. Envoi de photos sur demande.

</p>
```

Comment: Glad I could help. Please make sure to accept the answer :)

Comment: i'm new here. How do i do that? :)

Comment: Click on the "√" button, in the top-left corner of the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you add the pre-line attribute and have a manually line break right after you open the

tag the pseudo class first-line will no take the actual first line into consideration, but the whitespace before it. if you remove the initial line break, it works.

But instead of relying on the code white space line breaks you could use multiple html block elements to style your content (because it looks like you want a headline element instead). then you are always on the safe side.

```css
p#texto_anuncio {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
p#texto_anuncio:first-line {
  color: #800000;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<p id="texto_anuncio">Vente d'un appartement entièrement rénové au coeur de xxxx situé Rua xxxxx.
  <b>Appartement de charme très lumineux, 4ème étage, sans ascenseur, 130 m2, 2 balcons, 1 grand balcon fermé.</b>
  - 6 pièces, dont 3 aveugles. - Cuisine - électroménagers intégrés. - 2 salles de bains modernes. - Finition design avec respect des matériaux anciens. - Parquet ancien bois massif rénové . - Climatisation. Envoi de photos sur demande.</p>
```